# How to run ./script/generate rx_config?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm a newbie and i'm working follow this link http://dima.github.com/2009/03/19/working-with-restfulx-model-attachments.html

But I stuck on the step run ./script/generate rx_config. I don't know how can I run it.
I tried to go to the path of folder script and typed generate rx_cofig on command line but it doesn't work.

C:\Data\Workspace\rx_model_attachments\script>generate rx_config

I got the error 'generate' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Anyone can tell me step by step of doing this. Big thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since you're on windows, you will need to preface all of the scripts in the scripts folder with ruby:

```
C:\Data\Workspace\rx_model_attachments\script>ruby script/generate rx_config
```

The usual hash-bang (#!) at the start of the script files to let the shell know which interpreter to run does not work on windows.

Comment: I did follow you said but there is an error -> 'ruby' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Comment: That means ruby isn't on your path. You'll need to do that as well.

Comment: The Ruby Installer http://rubyinstaller.org/ will install Ruby on your Windows machine so you can run this.